# Appveyor skip the "install" statement

Tags: continuous-integration, yaml, appveyor

I'm trying to tie my project to the AppVeyor. For my purposes I need some open sources libs. I've included those via `git submodule`.

The entire file looks like:

```yaml
version: 1.0.{build}

branches:
    only:
    - master

clone_folder: c:\projects\emscripten-opengl

install:
    - cd %APPVEYOR_BUILD_FOLDER%
    - git submodule update --init --recursive

image:
- Visual Studio 2019
- Visual Studio 2017

configuration:
- Debug
- Release

platform:
- x64

environment:
    matrix:
    - arch: Win64

init:
- set arch=
- if "%arch%"=="Win64" ( set arch= Win64)
- echo %arch%
- echo %APPVEYOR_BUILD_WORKER_IMAGE%
- if "%APPVEYOR_BUILD_WORKER_IMAGE%"=="Visual Studio 2017" ( set generator="Visual Studio 15 2017%arch%" )
- if "%APPVEYOR_BUILD_WORKER_IMAGE%"=="Visual Studio 2015" ( set generator="Visual Studio 14 2015%arch%" )
- if "%APPVEYOR_BUILD_WORKER_IMAGE%"=="Visual Studio 2013" ( set generator="Visual Studio 12 2013%arch%" )
- echo %generator%

before_build:
- cmd: |-
    mkdir build
    cd build
    cmake --version
    cmake -DENABLE_TESTS=ON .. -G %generator%

build:
    project: c:\projects\emscripten-opengl\build\Emscripten_Graphics.sln
    verbosity: minimal
    parallel: true
```

However, according to logs the install-rule is missing, for instance:

```
Build started
set arch=
if "%arch%"=="Win64" ( set arch= Win64)
echo %arch%
 Win64
echo %APPVEYOR_BUILD_WORKER_IMAGE%
Visual Studio 2017
if "%APPVEYOR_BUILD_WORKER_IMAGE%"=="Visual Studio 2017" ( set generator="Visual Studio 15 2017%arch%" )
if "%APPVEYOR_BUILD_WORKER_IMAGE%"=="Visual Studio 2015" ( set generator="Visual Studio 14 2015%arch%" )
if "%APPVEYOR_BUILD_WORKER_IMAGE%"=="Visual Studio 2013" ( set generator="Visual Studio 12 2013%arch%" )
echo %generator%
"Visual Studio 15 2017 Win64" 
git clone -q --branch=master https://github.com/JuiceFV/Emscripten_OpenGL.git c:\projects\emscripten-opengl
git checkout -qf 2b05c66d4fe51784238cef4016823482970e4345
mkdir build
cd build
cmake --version
cmake version 3.16.2
CMake suite maintained and supported by Kitware (kitware.com/cmake).
cmake -DENABLE_TESTS=ON .. -G %generator%
-- The C compiler identification is MSVC 19.16.27035.0
-- The CXX compiler identification is MSVC 19.16.27035.0
...
```

I've tried everything from [here](https://www.appveyor.com/docs/how-to/private-git-sub-modules/) and [here](https://www.appveyor.com/docs/how-to/private-git-sub-modules/), but nothing has worked. Where I did admit a mistake?

Comment: Could it be indentation (4 spaces) of items in `install` section?

Comment: No I've tried two options (w/ and w/o indention).

Answer (score 0):

YAML is sensitive to tabs and spaces, try format `install` section the same way as for example `init`.